# Basel Problem approximation error bounded by $\mathcal O(1/x)$?

Tags: approximation

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2315627) it is stated that
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac1{n^2}+\mathcal O(1/x).
$$
Is this statement true as $x\to\infty$?

What I've done: If $x$ is fixed, then I think the answer is almost trivial, because we may set $C=\pi^2x/6$, so
$$
\sum_{n=x}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{C}{x},
$$
therefore
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^2}=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{n=x}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^2}+C/x=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^2}+\mathcal O(1/x).
$$
But is there a constant independent of $x$ that makes this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula**

What is being referred to here is that
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{6n^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)
$$
This can be gotten using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). Thus, the constant is $1$.

---

**Integral Estimate for the Tail of the Series**

We also have the basic integral estimate for the tail of a monotonically decreasing series. This is based on the fact that
$$
\frac1{k^2}\le\int_{k-1}^k\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Summing this inequality yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}
&\le\int_n^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1n
\end{align}
$$

---

**Telescoping Series**

Using the simple inequality
$$
\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k
$$
we can sum, using the [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), to get
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1n
$$

---

**Example**
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\frac1{k^2}=1.6439345667
$$
whereas
$$
\frac{\pi^2}6=1.6449340668
$$
The error is $0.0009995001\lt\frac1{1000}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- is there a more elementary way to show that $\sum^\infty1/n^2=\sum_{n\leq x}1/n^2+\mathcal O(1/x)$ without using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula?

Comment: The Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula is essentially based in the integral approximation for the tail of the sum. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: I have added a third, and simpler, telescoping approach.

Comment: The second and third approaches are very clean and illuminating. Especially, the inequality in the third approach looks very clever. Thank you!